# SQLite character encoding for Google Gears

Tags: sqlite, utf-8, character-encoding, google-gears

We're using jQuery to get a JSON-string from our server (UTF-8 response, also UTF-8 request through jQuery) and put this JSON into a Google Gears WorkerPool. This workerpool processes the JSON and stores it into a Gears database (SQLite).

It turns out that, apparently, SQLite stores data using iso-8859-1 rather than UTF-8. Since we're trying to store user names that might contain Cyrillic characters (and others that you might encounter in Europe), this goes horribly wrong.

Can anyone tell me how to change the character encoding in either the Gears WorkerPool or the SQLite database that Gears employs? Of course, if I'm looking in the wrong direction with my problem, feel free to offer alternatives!

Unfortunately, HTML5 isn't an option as we're supposed to support IE7 primarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "PRAGMA encoding='utf-8' " before you define any tables.
see [This link](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_database.html#sqlite_changes)

And [this link](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) for SQLites PRAGMA syntax